# Crystal report not rendering on Mozilla FireFox browser but working on Chrome?

Tags: .net, google-chrome, firefox, crystal-reports, reporting

My crystal report either some time completely not appears or some time not rendered properly in crystal report viewer I am using latest version of firefox and crystal report v10 with .NET 4.5 I have attached image to problem . I tried many solution like adding meta tag

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

My viewer code is

```
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <cr:crystalreportviewer id="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" autodatabind="true"
        displaygrouptree="False" reuseparametervaluesonrefresh="True" printmode="ActiveX" />
</div>
</form>
```

What should i do to make crystal report 10 visible and render css properly as it is on chrome here is image
 [Image of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmkY2.png)

Comment: I have win 10 so IE 11 latest

Comment: ClientTarget="uplevel"  in page level resolves issue but header toolbar style not rendering